# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, amcharts4

I'm using all the latest versions of create-react-app, react, webpack, amcharts. I've implemented a amchart component with webpack, published that to our local npm registry and tried to import it in the create-react app. When I'm using the amchart component it is throwing an error like this

`webpackHotDevClient.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined`

I've tried with different versions of amcharts 4
These are the versions that I've used

- *create-react-app* - v3.0.1
- *amcharts* - v4.5.2
- *node* - v10.16.0
- *npm* - v6.9.0

```
//import packages
import React from "react";

//import components
import AMChart from "amchart";

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <div className="chart-container">
                <AMChart {...some props} />
            </div>

        );

    }

}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js (webpackHotDevClient.js:45)
    at a (amchart.js:25)
    at Object.0 (themes.css?9e0d:45)
    at a (amchart.js:25)
    at Module.<anonymous> (amchart.js:37186)
    at a (amchart.js:25)
    at push.../amchart/dist/amchart.js (amchart.js:136)
    at Object.../amchart/dist/amchart.js (amchart.js:137)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:786)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/components/AskLeniComponent.js (Images.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:786)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
```